# Same question listed twice in reputation list

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-history

This might not be a bug but I see the same question list twice in my reputation display, I know it is grouping things by a six hour difference, but is this really expected?

[image]

The first list says 2 events but shows all 5, similarly the second list says 3 events and shows all five.

Comment: Well, it grouped the events you hadn't seen separately from the ones you had. The request to get the expanded details doesn't differentiate, though, presumably because everything has been "seen" at that point.

Comment: I should note that I think the expansion behaviour isn't quite right, even if it's only a minor issue.

Comment: @TimStone - You should know by now I only bring up minor issues :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe so. If you had +20 from a question today, and +20 from a question tomorrow, they should show up on different days, so at the very least, the time subdivision should be 24 hrs.

Comment: That makes sense, but as I remember it, the whole history did not show up for both "events".

Comment: @Hogan If I have the same split, but let's say days apart, i.e. if suddenly 12 people upvoted my answer 3 days after I posted it, I would certainly want to be able to view the entire history at both days. It makes sense from a design standpoint, and honestly you won't open both full histories up if they are right next to each other, right?

Comment: except that is what I did because I was confused, why are there two listed, they were next to each other and I did not know what was going on.  * shrugs *