# Incorrect event count on reputation tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, reputation-history

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Same question listed twice in reputation list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141943/same-question-listed-twice-in-reputation-list)

In reputation tab of user profile (ordered by post), sometimes it displays incorrect count of events. Screenshot below shows 3 events but on drilldown 7 events are displayed:

[image]

This is the [actual HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/NQHTm/):

```
<table class="tbl-reputation">
    <tbody>

        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row rep-recent-row expandable-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
                    <span class="rep-up bounty-indicator-tab accept-indicator-tab">+45</span>
                                    </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 15:15:38Z">
                15:15
            </td>
                <td class="rep-desc">4 events</td>
                <td class="rep-link async-load load-prepped" data-load-url="/ajax/users/6266/rep/post/28618/1351814400/1351900800"><a class="load-body expander-arrow-small-hide" style=""></a>&nbsp;<a href="/questions/28615/buttons-placement-convention-in-android/28618#28618" class="answer-hyperlink ">Buttons placement convention in Android</a></td>
        </tr><tr class="loaded-body" style=""><td class="body-container body-loaded" colspan="4" style="height: 0px; padding: 0px; "><div style="display: none; ">
<div class="rep-breakdown">
<table class="tbl-reputation">
    <tbody>

        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
<span class="rep-up">+10</span>            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 15:15:38Z">
15:15            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was upvoted">upvote</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
<span class="rep-up">+10</span>            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 13:35:46Z">
13:35            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was upvoted">upvote</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
                <span class="rep-up bounty-indicator-tab accept-indicator-tab">+15</span>
            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 12:46:55Z">
12:46            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was accepted">accept</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
<span class="rep-up">+10</span>            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 12:24:01Z">
12:24            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was upvoted">upvote</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
<span class="rep-up">+10</span>            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 11:25:04Z">
11:25            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was upvoted">upvote</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
<span class="rep-up">+10</span>            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 07:46:22Z">
07:46            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was upvoted">upvote</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
<span class="rep-up">+10</span>            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 07:25:34Z">
07:25            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was upvoted">upvote</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div></div></td></tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row expandable-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
                    <span class="rep-up">+30</span>
                                    </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 11:25:04Z">
                11:25
            </td>
                <td class="rep-desc">3 events</td>
                <td class="rep-link async-load load-prepped" data-load-url="/ajax/users/6266/rep/post/28618/1351814400/1351900800"><a class="load-body expander-arrow-small-hide hide-body expander-arrow-small-show" style=""></a>&nbsp;<a href="/questions/28615/buttons-placement-convention-in-android/28618#28618" class="answer-hyperlink ">Buttons placement convention in Android</a></td>
        </tr><tr class="loaded-body" style=""><td class="body-container body-loaded" colspan="4" style="height: 161px; "><div style="display: block; ">
<div class="rep-breakdown">
<table class="tbl-reputation">
    <tbody>

        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
<span class="rep-up">+10</span>            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 15:15:38Z">
15:15            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was upvoted">upvote</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
<span class="rep-up">+10</span>            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 13:35:46Z">
13:35            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was upvoted">upvote</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
                <span class="rep-up bounty-indicator-tab accept-indicator-tab">+15</span>
            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 12:46:55Z">
12:46            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was accepted">accept</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
<span class="rep-up">+10</span>            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 12:24:01Z">
12:24            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was upvoted">upvote</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
<span class="rep-up">+10</span>            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 11:25:04Z">
11:25            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was upvoted">upvote</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
<span class="rep-up">+10</span>            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 07:46:22Z">
07:46            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was upvoted">upvote</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="rep-breakdown-row">
            <td class="rep-left">
<span class="rep-up">+10</span>            </td>
            <td class="rep-time" title="2012-11-02 07:25:34Z">
07:25            </td>
            <td class="rep-desc" title="answer was upvoted">upvote</td>
                    <td class="rep-link">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div></div></td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: From where that screenshot is taken?

Comment: I saw same behavior on both Meta.SO and UX.SE. This one is from UX.SE

Comment: (Just guessing from the screen shot) This may be because when you load that page, there were only 3 events and before you expand it, you got another 3 upvotes and acceptance of your answer. So it shows 3 events in title and 7 events in detail.

Comment: Did you try refreshing the page or clearing the cache? It shows "7 events" for me.

Comment: I dont think it is a cache issue, I have posted HTML code it shows 7 rows after it displays '3 events'

Comment: @AzizShaikh: the rows below are loaded with AJAX, so the HTML is for these are loaded separately. Thus, caching can be a factor, as is timing (opening the drill-down after loading the page).

Comment: @AzizShaikh: Moreover, the server could be employing caches for various queries; one for the overall event counts, and one for detail queries, and *those* caches could be out of sync from time to time.

Comment: The "3 events" timestamp is 11:25, and that's consistent with 3 events before that time.

Comment: I have updated the screenshot. This is what was displayed, 4 events and 3 events separately.

Comment: Can't reproduce; I also think it's local browser cache. Did you try clearing it?

Comment: It is coming up fine now but I have captured/posted the HTML which clearly shows 2 separate rows (one showing '3 events' and second showing '4 events' for the same post). It could be a server-side cache issue but can't be client-side cache problem.

Comment: Right, the issue is just that the details view doesn't take into account that there was a separation between the new and old reputation groups on the page.

Comment: Nice find, @Tim!